# open new shell from resourcechangeListener

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have added a resource change listener to my plugin. From this listener class i want to show a message to the user using MessageDialog. Below is the code:

```
public class MyResourceChangeListener implements IResourceChangeListener {
    public void resourceChanged(final IResourceChangeEvent event) {                
         MessageDialog.openWarning(new Shell(),"some thing","something");
    }
}
```

When i execute this code i get the below error:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
```

Can you please point out anything wrong in the code and suggest the right way to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to run UI code on a non-UI thread, which is impossible.
Use this to run your code on an UI thread:

```
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
          MessageDialog.openWarning(new Shell(),"some thing","something");
    }
});
```

As the method says, it is an asynchronous call, so don't expect it to block your method execution.

Comment: Inside the above run method i want to open a question dialog, and use the returned boolean value in the resourceChanged mathod. Please suggest a way to do that.

Comment: You can put your code in the run() method. Since the MessageDialog block the interactions with the UI, it shouldn't be an issue.